# Адаптивная верстка не работает на iPhone

Tags: css, ios, iphone, adaptive, adaptive-design

Я работаю над проектом с адаптивной версткой веб-сайта, но по какой-то причине медиа-запрос не работает на iPhone (хотя на других устройствах он отлично работает). Поскольку у меня довольно много кода, я создал новый пустой HTML-файл, чтобы показать проблему. В следующем примере цвет фона не меняется, если я открываю веб-сайт на iPhone. Страница: https://dobrocenter.fi/test.html В чем проблема и как ее решить? Спасибо! Вот мой HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./test.css">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
   background-color: #000;
}
@media(420px>=width) {
   body{
      background-color: #e64f4f;
   }
}
```

Comment: А собственно где вы видели реализацию именно таким образом медиа запроса?

Comment: Читайте [документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#formal_syntax), там совсем другой синтаксис.

Comment: Такой синтаксис по моему тоже добавили, но не уверен что в точности такой. Допустим в самом конце приведенной ссылки, разве не похожее?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю что не так с медиа запросом, как его исправить?